# What adjective can I use to describe someone who is promiscuous, uses drugs, etc.?

Tags: word-request

What adjectives can I use to describe people who are promiscuous, use drugs, and do other things that are traditionally frowned upon by society, especially the older generation (like the teenagers from the TV series *Euphoria*)? I feel like I forgot some word for that but thesaurus couldn't help me. I would appreciate if you offered several options belonging to different styles (neutral, formal, slang).

Comment: Dissolute......

Comment: @user105719 Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You might say they were *reckless*, or *lived / behaved recklessly*.

This [article](http://content.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,1907750,00.html) titled "why do some teens behave recklessly" uses that expression to describe:

> "the cavalier behaviour of teenagers — driving too fast, engaging in unprotected sex, dabbling in illicit drugs"